Metodo de la potencia en Maple, error printf
Tengo un codigo en Maple que estoy utilizando para calcular el autovector maximo de una ecuación discretizada que representa el flujo de Poiseuille por metodo de la potencia, el código se hace hasta el punto en el que da este error
Error, (in fprintf) number expected for floating point format
No dice la linea pero se supone que el error está en este fragmento, se supone que imprima el autovector dominante, pero retorna un error pues se supone que deberia recibir un flotante, el programa se crashea al intentar cambiar el printf por print.
            printf("Convergencia alcanzada en la iteración %d\n", iterations);
            printf("Autovector dominante:\n");
            for i from 1 to n+1 do
                printf("%.10f\n", evalf(v0[i])); # Convertimos v0[i] a punto flotante antes de imprimirlo
            end do;
            printf("Autovalor dominante: %.10f\n", evalf(lambda1)); # Modificado el formato de impresión y aseguramiento de que lambda1 sea un número en punto flotante

Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionarlo?
No adjunto el codigo completo pues no me lo permite la pagina.
